# MySQL query to select only entries where value = X and value <> Y

Tags: mysql

Raw MySQL queries are absolutely *not* my forte, so I'm struggling with this a bit, but: with a straightforward table layout like this:

```
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| id | status_id | order_id | created_at          |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |     1     |     1    | 2016-03-21 20:40:39 |
|  2 |     3     |     1    | 2016-03-21 20:40:45 |
|  3 |     5     |     1    | 2016-03-21 20:47:14 |
|  4 |     1     |     2    | 2016-03-25 12:14:44 |
|  6 |     3     |     2    | 2016-03-25 12:16:12 |
|  7 |     5     |     2    | 2016-03-25 12:47:43 |
|  8 |     1     |     3    | 2016-03-26 17:25:12 |
|  9 |     3     |     3    | 2016-03-26 17:25:48 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

I want to select only the `order_id` rows where the `status_id` equals `3`, but not where that same `order_id` has a `status_id` of `5`. As a result, my query should only return order ID **3**, but my current query returns all 3 order IDs in the results:

```
$statusQueryString = 'SELECT DISTINCT order_id 
    FROM shop_order_status_log_records 
    WHERE status_id = 3 AND status_id <> 5 ORDER BY created_at';
```

Where am I going wrong with my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use post aggregate filtering when you need 2 or more conditions per group.A simple rule WHERE filters rows HAVING filters groups

```
SELECT order_id  FROM shop_order_status_log_records 
GROUP BY order_id 
HAVING SUM(status_id = 3)>0
AND SUM(status_id = 5)=0
```

Comment: _Thank you_. I think it's safe to say that I wouldn't have figured that one out for quite some time. Consider yourself accepted in... 9 minutes!